# WPF textbox's toolip foreground not changing

Tags: wpf

I have created a customized textbox which have a property SelfPropertyInfo. This again have some other property which we use(like IsValid, Description etc). I am trying to add style on text box so that if if IsValid is false it should show a tooltip(which contains Description).

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">            
    <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value=" Red "/>            
</Style>    

<Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControls:TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.IsValid}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}" >
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

By above code everything is working fine, but the issue is that the tooltip is not in "Red" color. :(
Can anybody suggest?

I tried another approach and the foreground is now "Red", but I need help about how TO bind description with tootip's text. Please see the changes inside DataTrigger, :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.IsValid}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
          <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                       <ToolTip >
                           <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Hello"/>
                       </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
 </DataTrigger>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

I also tried below code, but it makes tooltip blank:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.IsValid}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip >
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
```

Comment: `DataContext` of `ToolTip` should be the same as `TextBox`. Did you try same binding that you use in `CustomControls:TextBox.ToolTip` in `TextBlock.Text`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I tried but tooltip text remains blank..
See what I diid:

 <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>

Answer (score 0):

In the DataTrigger, "Text" property of TextBlock used to set Foreground for tooltip is overriding the Tooltip's text value, thats why you're unable to see the description. So bind the "Text" property with SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription.

Comment: Please see recent added code in my question, I tried what you are saying, but it makes tooltip blank.

Comment: Can you please debug it, that trigger is fired and what value comes in SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription. You can just simple use a dummy converter to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out using normal property it worked fine for me

```
        private string testString;    
        public string TestString
        {
            get { return testString; }
            set
            {
                testString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TestString");
            }
        }

  <TextBox  Height="100" Text="{Binding TestString}">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestString}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ToolTip >
                                            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding TestString}"/>
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But It will not help me. You have added styles in your textbox explicitly, however my requirement is to create a reusable style of TargetType=CustomControls:TextBox.